# Anthropometric z-scores (WHO package Anthro) and keeping the IDs

Tags: r

I am using "Anthro" R-package by the WHO to calculate the standardized-z-score for children nutritional status. The package is working fine but it is returning the results without the corresponding IDs. The results are in the right order, but I wish there was a way to keep the IDs with the z-scores.

Sample data set:

```
    
ID     age(in months)     gender   height(cm)   weight (kg)
---------------------------------------------------------
1345   12                  F          64             7 
2375   16                  F          70             7.5
3126   24                  M          70             8
```

Using the following package and code:

```
library(anthro)

with(
sample_data,
anthro_zscores(
sex = gender, age = age, is_age_in_month= TRUE,
weight = weight(kg), lenhei = height(cm)
)
)
```

The results are only the z-score of the children which does not include the IDs. How do I keep the IDs with the results?

Code is in R. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is a `data.frame` and it returns the same number of rows as initial data.  So, we could `cbind` the 'ID' column from original data

```
library(anthro)
out1 <- cbind(ID = sample_data$ID, out)
```

where

```
out <- with(
 sample_data,
   anthro_zscores(
   sex = gender, age = `age(in months)`, is_age_in_month= TRUE,
      weight = `weight (kg)`, lenhei = `height(cm)`
        )
      )
```

#### data

```
sample_data <- structure(list(ID = c(1345L, 2375L, 3126L), `age(in months)` = c(12L, 
16L, 24L), gender = c("F", "F", "M"), `height(cm)` = c(64L, 70L, 
70L), `weight (kg)` = c(7, 7.5, 8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```